# unable to test android application on HTC wildfire

Tags: android, htc-android

I have a htc wildfire phone and i have developed one application in android 2.1 using eclipse IDE now its time to run it on the actual device.

so far i have done following.

1. i have set my application as "debuggable" in my Android Manifest.
2. i have download the driver that is setup_3.0.5511.exe (HTC Sync)
3. i have connect my device via usb to my pc.
4. i tried running abd devices and its giving me 'HTXXXXXXXX device'

apart form these when i operate something in my phone i can see the log information in my eclips LogCat section.

Moreover when i open  Android SDK and AVD Manager all i can see the Virtual devices listed ; there is not actual physical device is shown over here.

I am using Windows XP operating system and ***HTC Wildfire phone.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical device will not be listed in the AVD manager.  I'm not sure how things work in Eclipse but from the command line you can run the following command to install an APK on your phone:

```
adb -d install -r yourapp.apk
```

The `-d` specifies that you want to install on a device rather than the emulator.  The `-r` just means that the app will be reinstalled if it already exists.

Comment: You can do it in eclipse by editing your run configuration and changing the Deployment Target Selection Mode in the Target Tab to Manual.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to enable USB debugging in the phone settings, see [this link](http://www.technixupdate.com/turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-in-nexus-one-or-other-android-phone/)